# /usr/sbin/sendmail to send mail with attachemnt of .html

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am using `/usr/sbin/sendmail` to send mail with attachment of .html

can you please let us know the correct command ?

```
(cat report.html) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Comment: Do you have to use sendmail?  If not, see this page: http://www.tecmint.com/send-email-attachment-from-linux-commandline/

Answer (score 1):

`sendmail` expects message in "raw" format (header+empty line+body).
Generate MIME headers specifying message body as html. 
See shell script below for example.

```
#!/bin/sh
MAILTO=john.doe@example.com    

cat - report.html << END | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- $MAILTO
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: Report
To: $MAILTO

END
```